# lxml's parser target does not fire 'start' callback immediately, when it is fed an opening tag

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I was trying to use lxml's [parser target interface](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#the-target-parser-interface) to incrementally parse XML into a 'custom' tree and I've come across the following problem: if you instantiate the parser and immediately feed it the opening tag of the root element, the 'start' callback of the target does not fire until any other event occurs (such as incoming data, closing tag, another opening tag, etc). This does not seem to happen to any other (nested) elements.

Demonstration:

```
class EchoTarget(object):
    def start(self, tag, attrib):
        print("start %s %s" % (tag, attrib))
    def end(self, tag):
        print("end %s" % tag)
    def data(self, data):
        print("data %r" % data)
    def comment(self, text):
        print("comment %s" % text)
    def close(self):
        print("close")
        return "closed!"

>>> p = etree.XMLParser(target=EchoTarget())
>>> p.feed('<a>') # nothing happens
>>> p.feed(' ') # suddenly..
start a {}
>>> p.feed('<b>') # works as expected
data u' '
start b {}
```

There is a way to work around this:

```
>>> p = etree.XMLParser(target=EchoTarget())
>>> p.feed(' ')
>>> p.feed('<a>')
start a {}
```

What's the explanation for this? And is the workaround "valid"? That is, is it safe to rely on this behaviour to ensure, that the very first opening tag in the stream will fire the 'start' callback?

By the way, there is another way to achieve this result:

```
>>> p = etree.XMLParser(target=EchoTarget())
>>> p.feed('<a')
>>> p.feed('>')
start a {}
```

However, breaking up the stream into 2-character-length chunks seems to be a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem? The event is triggered always, just a bit later than you expect. But the order is preserved and everything... Seems like no events are triggered on the very first feed, no matter what.

Comment: @LevLevitsky well, it, unfortunately, *is* a bit of a problem for my application

Comment: @shylent did you report it to lxml creator? It might just be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the documentation it seems this is the expected behaviour (quoting from http://lxml.de/parsing.html#the-feed-parser-interface):

> "If you do not call close(), the parser will stay locked and
>   subsequent feeds will keep appending data, usually resulting in a non
>   well-formed document and an unexpected parser error. So make sure you
>   always close the parser after use, also in the exception case."

So the parser is 'waiting' for more to be fed or to be closed. You can verify that what you are feeding is not valid XML (yet) by calling the close method:

```
>>> p.feed('<a>')
>>> p.close()
start a {}
close
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "parser.pxi", line 1171, in lxml.etree._FeedParser.close (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:79791)
  File "parsertarget.pxi", line 128, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.
c:88895)
  File "parser.pxi", line 590, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74696)
XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 1, column 4
```

So for example closing the opened tag (valid XML) will produce:

```
>>> p = etree.XMLParser(target=EchoTarget())
>>> p.feed('<a>')
>>> p.feed('</a>')
start a {}
end a
```

Hope this helps.